# Faker could not be resolved, tried everything

Tags: python, warnings

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPZ7.png)

```
import os
from faker import Faker
import random
import string

# Create an instance of the Faker class
fake = Faker()

def generate_random_combination():
    password = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=8))
    name = fake.name()
    email = fake.email()

    return password, email

def save_to_file(file_path, lines):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        for password, email in lines:
            file.write(f'{password}, {email}\n')

# Create a path for the file on the desktop
desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
file_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'random_values.txt')

# Specify the number of lines to generate
num_lines = 10

# Generate and save data to a file
random_lines = [generate_random_combination() for _ in range(num_lines)]
save_to_file(file_path, random_lines)

print(f'Generated combinations saved to file: {file_path}')
```

the error

```
 File "c:\Users\ostar\Documents\programming\python\python character generator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from faker import Faker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'faker'
```

I tried reinstalling faker, instaliing anaconda and pycharm, i'm originally doing this in vscode, standard visual studio gives the same error. Even tried a virtual enviorment, didn't work.